# How to configure a wireless router when mac address filtering is enabled by the ISP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I am using i-on internet and they store the mac address of the PC and provide internet only for that PC. I want to configure a wireless router and I didn't get any help from them. Is it even possible to connect a wireless router for that network. If yes, How can I do that?

PS: I am not sure whether it is correct section to post this question or not. But I didn't know a better place.

Thanks Vinod

Comment: Call them up and request they whitelist the MAC address for your router

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in most cases you can do this. You did not define what brand of router, so this is a rather vague answer.

In most broadband router setup configuration there is an option to clone your PC's MAC address or manually enter a user defined MAC address. This allows the router to appear to be your PC while connected to your ISP.

[image]